# Ordering Classes in a Component Based Game

Tags: c++, components

I am writing a simple Pacman clone in C++ using SDL. I want to try my hand at writing it with a component based design, because I believe when I begin to code more complex games, this knowledge will make things easier. I've learned that there are a lot of different approaches to component based game design, but the simplest and most complete example that I could find comes from the book *[Game Programming Patterns](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html)* by Bob Nystrom. From what I've read online the way it is done in this book may be considered somewhat clunky when compared to something like an entity system, but I figured this could be a good place to start.

What Nystrom does in his example is to create a generic GameObject class that holds pointers to objects of each component class. The following is some test code of mine that follows his example:

```
class GameObject
{
protected:
    InputComponent* input_;

public:
    float xvel, yvel;
    float xpos, ypos;

    GameObject(InputComponent* input) : input_(input)
    {   };

    void update()
    {
        input_->update(*this);
    }
};

class InputComponent
{
protected:
    //Input variables

public:

    void update(GameObject& character)
    {
        //Takes user input and updates character accordingly
    }
};
```

This is the basic design pattern used in the book. Using it you should be able to instantiate an object of the class GameObject and give it an InputComponent. According to Nystrom that would work something like this:

```
GameObject* character = new GameObject(new InputComponent())
```

Then the game object can be updated by simply calling the update function on the character object, which would in turn update all of the components (in this case, I only have the input component set up).

This all makes sense, except I have run into a problem. Because the GameObject class holds an object from InputComponent, and InputComponent has a function that takes a GameObject as an argument my code won't compile. If I place the GameObject class first in my code then it says InputComponent inside the GameObject class is an unknown type. If I place the InputComponent class first then it says that GameObject inside the InputComponent class is an unknown type. I believe I have followed Nystrom's example very closely (granted, I simplified a lot of the code because I'm just starting), so I believe I have either misunderstood Nystrom's example, or there is a mistake in his code.

So, this is my question: Is it possible to build the component system in this way? Is there something simple that I am missing, or is this type of "one class calling another class's object, and vice versa" illegal in C++?

Comment: Seems you have to forward declare, instead of using `#include`.

Comment: Wow, so simple. Thank you, I hadn't heard of forward declaring before, but it worked.